# WPF datagrid with ToggleButton binding

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, togglebutton

I'm relatively new to WPF and am having a hard time binding a custom class to a datagrid. While the text properties are OK (they are read-only anyway), the togglebuttons for the boolean properties are not updated in my item list, and they are also not displayed according to the values set initially. They do however respond correctly to clicks in the UI.

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleImageStyleBien" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Name="img" Source="Images/transp.png"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="Images/good.png"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here's the DataGrid itself:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" Name="dataGridRevision" Width="Auto" Margin="6,6,6,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalGridLinesBrush="{x:Null}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Descripción" Binding="{Binding Description}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Bien">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource ToggleImageStyleBien}" Click="ToggleButton_Click" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=ReviewItem.Good, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Comentario" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is the class I'm binding to:

```
public class ReviewItem
{
    public string Code { set; get; }
    public string Description { set; get; }
    public bool Good { set; get; }
    public bool Bad { set; get; }
    public string Comment { set; get; }
}
```

As far as I can tell, I'm not using the right Binding property in the ToggleButton, but I have tried a lot and have run out of ideas. The list properties are not changing on click, the values are not displayed according to the data.

Please help...

Thanks!

Joerg.

Changed the class to this, based on other examples found:

```
public class ReviewItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Code { set; get; }
    public string Description { set; get; }
    public bool Bad { set; get; }
    public string Comment { set; get; }

    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool Good
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Good = " + value);
            _isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Good");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently binding to `UserControl.ReviewItem`, which is not a valid property on a `UserControl`.

Try binding to `DataContext.ReviewItem` instead which will bind to `UserControl.DataContext.ReviewItem`

If you do not mean to bind to `UserControl.DataContext.ReviewItem.Good`, and instead want to bind to `DataGrid.ReviewItems[x].Good`, then you only need to bind `IsChecked="{Binding Good}"`. This is because the default `DataContext` on a `DataGridCell` is the row's data item, so if your collection contains a list of `ReviewItems`, the DataContext of the cell is already set to a `ReviewItem`

Also, I would highly recommend using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) for debugging WPF bindings. You can use it on your application to see what the `DataContext` is for individual UI Elements, and figure out if your bindings are correct or not.

Comment: Hi Rachel! First of all, thanks a lot for responding. And please excuse my late reply, because this was my first post here and I thought I'd get an e-mail notification when someone responds.
As to your suggestion, I guess the line I would have to change, is the following, right?
`<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource ToggleImageStyleBien}" Click="ToggleButton_Click" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=ReviewItem.Good, Mode=TwoWay}" />`
What would be the correct solution here?
Thanks again,
Joerg.

Comment: When I change the binding to `<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource ToggleImageStyleBien}" Click="ToggleButton_Click" IsChecked="{Binding Good}" />` I get no binding error in Snoop. Yet the ReviewItems collection still doesn't have the true or false value updated... I am using this to check the values:
`foreach (ReviewItem it in ReviewItems) { textBoxComments.Text += it.Description + ": " + it.Good.ToString() + "\r\n"; }`

Comment: @user1058209 You need to change your binding from `ReviewItem.Good` to `DataContext.ReviewItem.Good`, because `UserControl` does not have a property called `ReviewItem`, but `UserControl.DataContext` does. `<ToggleButton ... IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ReviewItem.Good, Mode=TwoWay}" />`

Comment: Thank you. But this gives me following binding error in Snoop:

System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.ReviewItem.Good; DataItem=null; target element is 'ToggleButton' (Name=''); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1')

I guess I am missing something else... :-(

Comment: @user1058209 It's telling you it can't find the `RelativeSource` objecct, which is the `UserControl`. I am assuming that the `UserControl` you are trying to find is further up the hierarchy from the `ToggleButton`? If not, try giving it a `x:Name` and use `{Binding ElementName=MyUserControlName, Path=DataContext.ReviewItem.Good}`

Comment: The thing with the UserControl is probably a result of a copy/paste from another example. Actually I don't have a control called UserControl. So how would I have to define the `RelativeSource`? I have the `ReviewItems` collection simply as a member of the `MainWindow`...

Comment: OK, if I use the following, the data -> UI binding seems to work, since I can then set the property on any ReviewItem in code and see that reflected in the UI.
`<ToggleButton ... IsChecked="{Binding Path=Good, Mode=TwoWay}" />`
 However, clicking the ToggleButton does change its visual, but it does not update my `ReviewItems` list...

Comment: Finally think I figured it out! In addition to all the above, I had to add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the ToggleButton. Now my ToggleButton can update the datasource correctly. Thanks a lot for your pointers, Rachel!

Comment: @Joerg - these 2 things fixed my issue also - thanks :-)